# RajawaliVuforia how to set up new tracker image?

Tags: android, vuforia, tracker, rajawali

Can any one describe what exactly I have to do to create new image marker ? 
and what I have to set instead of this two values to use my cloud library ? library key ? and what is the other value ?

```
setCloudRecoDatabase("a75960aa97c3b72a76eb997f9e40d210d5e40bf2",
"aac883379f691a2550e80767ccd445ffbaa520ca");
```

can I create a tracker without cloud recognition ?